# How to populate a content driven hybrid mobile app?

Tags: mobile, cordova, telerik, hybrid

I'm trying to develop a hybrid app which will deliver a range of simple teaching material to the user. I am planning on using Telerik App Builder in conjunction with Cordoba 3 to create the app. What I cannot decide  is how best to package the actual content into the application. I'd like to achieve a separation of the content from the code, and just combine the two when building the delivery packages. (The content is being prepared by a subject matter expert.)
Is there a way I can use Cordova or Telerik AppBuilder to pre-populate a SQLite database as part of the app install process? Or am going about this in completely the wrong way? I have been researching this in the Telerik documentation but without success so far. If someone could point me towards a suitable example or even the correct places in the Telerik or Cordova docs I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran a techie webinar on the topic. The main idea is that you need a centralized system to host this content and this system needs to expose some kind of a service layer that will feed content to your app. To me this seems like a very growing market opportunity, but feels kinda the same as the web 1.0 days where all of us were trying to figure out how to feed cotnent to websites and everybody was building their own CMS in a way.

Telerik Backend Services provides an editing interface, so it can fit some requirements, but it's not a publishing system, plus you may not want to pay developer licenses to your back-end users or provide them with access. The premise of the webinar I am talking about was that we discussed how to integrate with another telerik product - Sitefinity to do this job for you instead. The first 20-25 minutes are an overview of the platfrom, so if you have seen it already, you can certainly jump to ~;0:25 to see the rest

http://www.sitefinity.com/campaigns/webinars/build-content-driven-mobile-apps

Now certainly it doesn't have to be Sitefinity or CMS for that matter, Sitefinity provides a bunch of App Builder related features that are handy, but you technically have a few options:
- Build your own applicaiton and back-end. 
- Use any type of CMS or platform that will give your SMEs the back-end interface to publish and the service layer to expose to the app. In the webinar I also go through some neat tricks such as using push notifications upon publishing.

This way you get a clear separation of content and code - you can even get a separation of content structure and code, which is an idea i talk about in greater detail.

I hope this helps!

Svetla